# Simulated Annealing with real value maximisation

Tags: c++, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, simulated-annealing

I am working on simulated annealing trying to solve the knapsack problem whereby I have to maximise the fitness (value of the item in the bag).

```
float weight[5]={2, 3, 5, 4, 3}; // weight
float value[5]={10, 20, 15, 25, 5}; // value of corresponding item
float bagSize = 11.0;
```

By hard calculation we know that the best solution is {1,1,0.4,1,0}. However I don't get this solution.

I will explain my c++ code in pseudo-code to avoid all the long codes here.

```
While (temperate > 1){
  1) Generate random values between (0,1) to fill the 5 sized array for each item
  2) Perform random swapping of values in the 5D array above.
  3) Calculate the fitness and new weight
  4) Save the best solution. 
}
```

Basically this is my code in short. My question

1. In step 2 when performing swapping, currently I am swapping elements of the array. Is it correct? Or should I keep track of the previous solution and swap current element (i) with previous solution element? (This is just an idea).
2. When using real values in the array how can I tell the system during execution that the previous solution was close to the max boundary because in my current implementation I continuous generate the random values in step one which is repeated until the system cools.

Lastly, maybe there are some huge mistake in my implementation, I really appreciate if  I can be helped out in this problem

Comment: This does not even look like simulated annealing, you should correct your pseudocode, or better - include the actual implementation as it should be at most 20 lines long

Comment: Also note that simulated annealing is not guaranteed to find the global maximum except for certain classes of problems and with very slow cooling (even then, since Metropolis-Hastings converges to uniformly sampling from the modes of the distribution, you'll have to be sure you see all of the modes and then calculate the fitness at each one.) And especially for these painful combinatorial kinds of problems, simulated annealing can be very brittle. Running for X iterations gets you to a close solution, but you need X*(10^6) iterations to have a reasonable chance of getting the global best.

Comment: (This may not matter if your problem instance size is very small, but it still seems from your question that you're expecting simulated annealing to just give you the "right" answer.)

Comment: Actually, my first assumption was that but later I realised that the solution I get may be close to the Gobal Max but it may not be the Gobal Max.

Answer (score 2):

Your pseudo code is not simulated annealing. You are randomly jumping in search space without any aim.

Your first question:

> In step 2 when performing swapping, currently I am swapping elements of the array. Is it correct? Or should I keep track of the previous solution and swap current element (i) with previous solution element? (This is just an idea).

You should implement a function called perturb. This perturb should exchange your array values.Simulated Annealing , as its name implies uses concept of annealing. That means you start hot. Your perturb function changes values wildly.Then your solution starts cooling down that means your perturb function changes values only a little.

See following [presentation](http://www.sph.umich.edu/csg/abecasis/class/2006/615.19.pdf)

> z Gradual cooling of liquid …
>
> - At high temperatures, molecules move freely
> - At low temperatures, molecules are "stuck"

According to your solution , you get your randomness in following line.

> 2) Perform random swapping of values in the 5D array above.

Here is how you should implement Gradual cooling.

- 2a) int MaxRandomValueToAddToArrayValues = 20;
- 2b) How did I find 20, it is domain knowledge. According to your values and best solution 20 seems a good value.
- 2c) Perform random swapping of values in the 5D array above using this boundary
- 2d) gradually decrease MaxRandomValueToAddToArrayValues. For example for every 10 iteration you may decrease it by 0.1.

Your second question:

> When using real values in the array how can I tell the system during execution that the previous solution was close to the max boundary

You cannot know if your solution is close to max boundary. You can only know that your solution is better than previous ones. If we can know max boundary why implement SA or any other heuristic method. It is impossible or very expensive to know best solution (in your word max boundary), therefore we use heuristic solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I see all I was going wrong. Just a question, in my while statement above, like you said I am just searching without aim and I think that is the first step? If I eliminate the first step, and where I am randomly assigning values and implement something like a perturb as you said. Sorry I am quite lost in this AI things.

Comment: Also actually I got this psudocode from Wikipedia and it says pick some neighbours so to which I implemented the step 1 in the loop above.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing

Comment: oh thank you that seems to help. I have few question if you could help me in that. 1) Like you stated decrease it gradually say after 10 iteration. Does this mean than my max temperature is 20 or should i place a loop inside the while loop such that i decrease the max array value in every lowering of the temperature and obtain the best fitness solution?